# How to know language of pdf file in android using itext library?

Tags: android, android-edittext, itext

I am using itextg-5.5.4 for Extracting PDFs file text and show on Edit-text in android . When, i am Extracting English language PDF file text their is no problem,But when i am Extracting hindi or any other language PDF ,showing garbage as result on Edit-text.

So , is there any way to Extracting hindi language pdf file also and show on Edit-text.

OR

I can find out which Language PDf file is selected by user.So i can restrict them to choose only english PDFs file only.

Thanks!!!

My Code for Extracting text from pdf from internal storage is :-

```
String pat = data.getData().getPath();
File f = new File(pat);

read = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(f));

parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(read);

strw = new StringWriter();

stretegy = parser.processContent(j, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());

strw.write(stretegy.getResultantText());

String da = strw.toString();

edt1.setText(da);
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: There is no sure sign in generic PDFs allowing you to recognize whether or not you can properly extract text from them. Neither is there a sure way to recognize the language of a generic PDF.

Comment: Thanks You for the reply.

Comment: I see one more thing that , if i have 5 PDFs of suppose HINDI and I am trying to extracting text ,so from  2-3 PDFs out of 5 i am getting proper text .But from 2 PDFs i am getting Garbage.

Comment: And these 2-3 PDFs are completely in Hindi  language only not the combination of Hindi and English Language text.

Comment: As mentioned above, there is no generic test for that short of OCR'ing. If your PDFs are from a very few sources only, though, and these sources are known to have PDFs generated by a very limited selection of PDF generators only, you may produce a set of tests fitting these PDF generators.